# Classify each formal parameter of double-trouble as input output , input -output parameter

Tags: c

Classify each formal parameter of double-trouble as input output , input -output parameter

```
#include "stdio.h"


void double_trouble(int *p, int y){
  int x;
  x = 10;
  *p = 2 *  x - y;
}

void trouble(int *x, int *y){
  double_trouble(x, 7);
  double_trouble(y, *x);
}
int main()
{
  int x, y;
  trouble(&x, &y);
  printf("x = %d, y = %d\n",x, y);

  return (0);

}
```

I think

```
   Formal parameters                          Purpose In Called Function
         (double_trouble)                    (double_troble)
           int *p                              input/output parameter
           int y                               input parameter



     Formal parameters                          Purpose In Called Function
         (trouble)                    (trouble)
           int *x                              inputparameter
           int *y                           input/output parameter
```

Am I right , I am not sure whether I am correct or not

Comment: Am I right about the solution I provided?

Comment: In regard to a parameter directly, all parameters in C are input-only, because arguments are passed by value, and changing a parameter inside a function cannot change the argument in the caller. Parameters can be output or input-output only in an indirect sense, when the parameter is a pointer and we are referring to what the parameter points to. In that sense, the `p` of `double_trouble` is output-only, as what it points to is changed but not used. Then `*x` of `trouble` is changed (when `x` is passed to `double_trouble`) but not used before that, so it is output-only, not truly input-output.

Comment: Similarly, `*y` of `trouble` is changed (when `y` is passed to `double-trouble`) but not used, so `y` is output-only.